# English definition for "linguistic enclave"

Tags: word-meaning

I'm trying to write an English definition for "linguistic enclave". I haven't found any in a monolingual dictionary or on the Internet.
I came up with something like this:

> A portion of territory surrounded by a larger territory whose
>   inhabitants speak a dialect or language which is different from the
>   one of the inhabitants of the surrounding territory.

Is that correct English and does that reflect the true meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrase has the meaning you intend.

> linguistic enclave

An **enclave** is

> a portion of territory within or surrounded by a larger territory whose inhabitants are culturally or ethnically distinct.

So a **linguistic enclave** would be understood to mean an enclave that is defined by its language.